# Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. Memory leak on react-image-gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to implement the react-image-gallery v0.8.7 (0.8.8 has a [bug](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/issues/288)) from this npm package: [https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery](http://I've%20been%20trying%20to%20implement%20the%20react-image-gallery%20from%20this%20npm%20package:%20https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) and integrated following the [example](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery#example) as follows (I am developing a Meteor web app):

```
class MyGallery extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mediaSrc: [],
      isFullScreen: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const mediaSrc = this.props.myObject.pictures.map((picture) => {
      return { original: picture, thumbnail: picture };
    });
    this.setState({ mediaSrc });
  }

  _onImageClick(event) {
    if (this.state.isFullScreen) {
      this._imageGallery.exitFullScreen();
      this.setState({ isFullScreen: false });
    } else {
      this._imageGallery.fullScreen();
      this.setState({ isFullScreen: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dish row">
        <figure className="center col-12" >
          <div className="dish__preview_container">
            <ImageGallery
              ref={i => this._imageGallery = i}
              items={this.state.mediaSrc}
              onClick={this._onImageClick.bind(this)}
              showFullscreenButton={false}
              showIndex
              showPlayButton={false}
              showThumbnails={false}
            />
         </div>
      );
  }
}

MyGallery.propTypes = {
  myObject: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

}
```

The object `myObject` contains the following value in the pictures array:

```
[ 'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/6c/2b/9b/america-s-taco-shop.jpg',
  'https://www.cocinavital.mx/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/tostadas-de-tinga-de-pechuga-de-pollo-con-chipotle-video.jpg'
]
```

When rendering the ImageGallery is shown as expected, however when clicking on either the button aria-label="Previous Slide" or aria-label="Next Slide", doesn't show the respective image and throws the following exception on the developer tools console:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in ImageGallery (created by MyGallery)
    in div (created by MyGallery)
```

Any suggestions for a solution, please?

Update: Had a reset of component state variables on the componenteWillUmnount method. Removed it, also tried with [Meteor Reactive Dic](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict)t instead of component state variables. The exception remains, though.

Comment: Most likely caused by your `componentWillUnmount`. It looks like you're trying to "reset" the components state, but since the component is being unmounted, it will use the initial state in your constructor the next time it loads. So your reset here isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [React Official Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount), you should not call `setState()` in `componentWillUnmount` method because your component will never be re-rendered. To date, I only use this method to remove event listeners added in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Already did a refactor, revoming the componentDidMount(), also tried with Meteor Reactive Dict variables instead of component state variables. Had the same exception, though.

Comment: So eventually I realized that the problem was in setting a variable State in the parent component that contains MyGallery component. That being said, I will choose your answer as valid. Thank you for your response.